# Can't refresh data when user login using Vue.js

Tags: firebase, authentication, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and firebase.

I want to refresh my data when user is logged in.
I'm thinking about making a refresh method and trigger it `onAuthStateChanged`, but it just doesn't work( ERR: not defined ).

Below is my code, this is in an component file.

```
let auth = Firebase.auth()
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    refresh(user.uid,user.displayName)
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'chat_app',
  firebase: {...},
  data () {
    return {
      dialogNumber: 1,
      currentUserId: 1,
      currentUserName: 'A',
      ...
  },
  methods: {
    refresh: function (uid,displayName) {
      this.currentUserId = uid
      this.currentUserName = displayName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to make data reactive, you better define it inside data(){} object or try using mounted/updated life cycle hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onAuthStateChanged` callback, you're making a call to `refresh` which JS is understanding to be a function. You haven't defined any functions named `refresh`. What you have instead is a `refresh` method associated with Vue.

Consider using the `mounted` lifecycle hook and using `this.refresh`. Scoping will likely be an issue, however, so be sure to store your `this` reference in a variable:

```
mounted: function() {
    var this_vue_instance = this;
    
    let auth = Firebase.auth();
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            this_vue_instance.refresh(user.uid, user.displayName);
        }
    });
}
```

For more information on the `mounted` lifecycle hook, see the [relevant documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).